# Как сделать чтобы стиль, цвет background менялся в зависимости от дня и ночи?

Tags: javascript, css

Как сделать так, чтобы `с 6 утра до 12` часов стиль класса `bg` был одним, `с 12:01 до 19:00` другим, а `в 19:01` был третьим. При этом с `6-19` использовался такой тип кода цвета (`#ffffff`), а `c 19` такой (`radial-gradient(#1f64ff, transparent)`) ? Спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div')

// Получить текущее время
const currentTime = new Date()

// Для примера добавим переключение через 3 сек
// На деле просто устанавливаются часы
const targetTime = new Date()
targetTime.setSeconds(currentTime.getSeconds() + 3)

// Вычислить разницу между currentTime и targetTime
const diff = targetTime.valueOf() - currentTime.valueOf()

// Запустить перестановку класса в необходимое время
setTimeout(() => {
  div.classList.remove('day')
  div.classList.add('night')
}, diff)

// ... Осталось написать нужный код
```

```css
div {
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.day {
  background-color: #9e9e9e40;
  color: black;
}

.night {
  background-color: #9e9e9e;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="day">Фон</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Arcadiy Но 10-тью строчками тут не обойтись :). В реале надо определять с помощью `getМетодов` промежуток в котором находимся, и уже в зависимости от него отталкиваться что устанавливать. В конце для придется инкрементировать день, иначе `diff` уйдет в обратную сторону.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg А можете рассказать, как проще всего вычислить это самое  **необходимое время**, не запрашивая у пользователя разрешение на определение геопозиции? Как правильно найти границу между реальными днём и ночью за окном?

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov Светло/Темно без геопозиции определить нельзя - Зима/Лето в разных полушариях. JS сможет показать текущее время компьютера. Я, в сообщении выше, пытался сказать - что просто прибавить время нельзя. Например, мы зашли на страницу в 23:00, а следующее переключение в 06:00, значит необходимо инкрементировать день `setDate(1 день),setHours(6),min/sec:0`, так как следующий час(6) меньше текущего(23). В документации можно глянуть, некоторые инкременты раcсчитываются самостоятельно, некоторые нет - например setDate(32) сам прибавит месяц и установит 1-ое число.

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov Если необходимо примерно-точное определение "Светло/Темно" - геопозицию можно определить по IP-адресу пользователя, т.е. без запроса разрешения геолокации. Сам не пользовался, но наверняка на GitHub можно найти бесплатные библиотеки.